# Sorting numbers, but according to forth column

Tags: command, sort

## What do you want to achieve?

I have a 2 dimensional arrays of numbers like this:

```
[8,  18, 2, 20, 0]
[13, 18, 3, 15, 1]
[8,  18, 3, 30, 2]
[8,  13, 3, 15, 3]
[8,  13, 2, 10, 4]
[8,  15, 1, 7, 5]
[13, 18, 2, 10, 6]
[13, 17, 6, 24, 7]
[8,  13, 1, 5, 8]
[8,  13, 2, 10, 9]
[13, 18, 2, 10, 10]
[8,  13, 4, 20, 11]
[8,  12, 4, 16, 12]
[8,  13, 1, 5, 13]
[13, 15, 8, 16, 14]
[9,  14, 6, 30, 15]
[8,  14, 1, 6, 16]
```

Now I'd like to sort it according to the forth column so it looks like this:

```
[8,  13, 1, 5, 8]
[8,  13, 1, 5, 13]
[8,  14, 1, 6, 16]
[8,  15, 1, 7, 5]
[8,  13, 2, 10, 4]
[13, 18, 2, 10, 6]
[8,  13, 2, 10, 9]
[13, 18, 2, 10, 10]
[13, 18, 3, 15, 1]
[8,  13, 3, 15, 3]
[8,  12, 4, 16, 12]
[13, 15, 8, 16, 14]
[8,  18, 2, 20, 0]
[8,  13, 4, 20, 11]
[13, 17, 6, 24, 7]
[8,  18, 3, 30, 2]
[9,  14, 6, 30, 15]
```

## What have you tried?

I was using this command:

```
:sort r /\d\+,\s\d\+]/
```

to let vim look at the forth column.

## What's your question?

Is there a smarter way than doing this "long" sort command above? I can't find a parameter for `:sort` in `:h sort` which gives me the opportunity to "skip" a specifique amount of numbers. Something like

```
:sort 3n " 3 for 'third' and 'n' for decimal number
```

would be neat.

Comment: If you're on *nix type system just use the GNU tools sort: `:%!sort -n -k4` (If your target text is not the entire file replace `%` with the line range.)

Comment: I mean forth column. Thank you for the hint! I edited the title :)

Comment: No problem. Oh, and though it's been implied by your question being tagged as a duplicate, the answer to the question "is there a smarter way" is no; all the capabilities are captured in the help that you read. The linked answer gives a bit more insight into how to do it the "long" way. :) (My suggestion is to use the GNU sort if you have that. )